# Submitted data from NodeJS are undefined in Mysql Database

Tags: html, mysql, node.js

When i submitted the form data, the data added to mysql database and values shown as **Undefined**.
Can anyone show me whats the problem, I'm very new to NodeJs development.

> HTML doc

```
<html>

    <form method="post" action="/add">

    Name : <input   name="mname" type ="text" > <p>
    Age :  <input name="mage"   type ="text" > <p>
    Department : <input name="mdepartment"   type="text" > <p>
    City : <input   name="mcity" type = "text"> <p>

    <input type="submit" value ="submit">
    <input type="reset" value="reset"> 
    </form>
</center>
```

and My Javascript file as follows

> myapp.js

```
 var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var app = express();
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host : 'localhost',
    user : 'root',
    password : '1234'
});

connection.query('USE samplenodejs');

app.set('port',3000);


app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended : false}));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log('GET /');
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/AddDetails.html');
});


app.post('/add',function(req,res){

connection.query("INSERT INTO test VALUES('','"+req.body.mname+"','"+req.body.mage+"','"+req.body.mcity+"','"+req.body.mdepartment+"')",function(err,res){
    if(err) throw err;
});
res.redirect('/');

});


app.listen(app.get('port'));
console.log('Express server listening on port '+app.get('port'));
```

Comment: **Never** (blindly) concatenate user input in your SQL query strings, otherwise you open yourself up to SQL injection attacks. Always use prepared statements.

Comment: You need to put `res.redirect('/')` inside the query callback, otherwise, it will redirect before the query redirect before the query finishes. For the `undefined` problem, you can inspect the value of the form fields before the query. Then, you can inspect the whole SQL statement which is produced and try it directly in a mysql prompt or in phpmyadmin to see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am expecting you are getting valid data from the client. So below is the function to insert the data. Mysql string constants should be enclosed with `"` quotes.

```
app.post('/add',function(req,res){
    //Check this log in console, it should print all the values properly, if not issue is at clinet side
    console.log('Input:: name='+req.body.mname+' age='+ req.body.mage +' city='+ req.body.mcity + ' dep=' + req.body.mdepartment,   req.body);

    var Query = `INSERT INTO test (id, name, age, city, department) VALUES ("", "${req.body.mname}","${req.body.mage}","${req.body.mcity}","${req.body.mdepartment}" )`;

    //printing query in the console, if you still face the issue, you can execute this query manually.
    console.log("Query :" + Query );

    connection.query(Query, function(err,res){
        if(err) {
          console.error('Error in sql query:' + Query + ' Err', err);
          throw err;
        }
    });
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

> You should not pass the user input directly to SQL query, always need to do input validation.
>
> In NodeJs, its better to use JSON key:value pair for insertion as shown below
>   connection.query('INSERT INTO test SET ?', {name:req.body.mname, age:req.body.mage}, function(err, res) {});

Answer (score -1):

definitely the problem lies in your middleware body parser. Once re check the middleware and recheck the type of data your are sending to server

Comment: You can set a example instead of just type a message so end user will explain better

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).